# How to display the latest photo in a directory in real time?

Tags: video-streaming

I'm generating `.png` images with GnuPlot from a stream input and saving them into a folder in realtime. I want to display the latest image in a window as they are generated, like a realtime video streaming.

I have a loop where I can issue `thecommand path/to/latest/image.png` or I can overwrite to the same file (eg. `latest.png`) if it's more suitable for, eg., use with VLC, ffmpeg or mplayer.

How can I display different images within the same image viewer process and update it?

OS: Linux (Debian)

Comment: `inotifywait` should work fine for that purpose.

Comment: No need for `inotifywait` since I'm generating the images, so I can generate an appropriate event for the `command` that displays the image.

Comment: Wayland or X11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are image viewers that will auto-reload automatically an image
when it's modified.

You could, when a new image arrives, copy and overwrite the image
in the viewer with the new image (same image all the time),
so that the viewer will always show the latest one.

Some viewers are advised in
[link1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167808/image-viewer-with-auto-reload-on-file-change)
and
[link2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684392/how-to-continuously-display-the-newest-version-of-an-image-file-on-linux) :

- The old Gnome image viewers
  [Eye of Gnome](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EyeOfGnome)
  and
  [eye of mate](http://mate-desktop.org/)
- KDE's `okular`
- https://gitlab.com/dknof/siv
- `sxiv`
- `feh` can reload a file with a command such as the following
  (no need to copy files):
  `feh --reload 0.1 picture.png`

Comment: I copied latest image to `/dev/shm/latest.png` (into RAM) everytime it changes and run `feh --reload 0.1 /dev/shm/latest.png` in another terminal. That worked very smoothly.

Comment: Update: I found `sxiv` the more useful than `feh` and `qiv`.